# Table rate configuration

Tags: magento2, shipping

I work with Magento 2.2.2
and I am trying to add different prices for different cities in my country.

I have only 2 shipping rates! One for my City and another for rest of my country: Norway.

Can I add the name of my City, “Oslo” in the “Region/State” and “*” for rest of the country?

Like this? would it calculate the shipping price correct?

> “Country” “Region/State”  “Zip/Postal Code”   “Order Subtotal (and above)”    “Shipping Price”
>   NOR   Oslo    *   0   120
>   NOR   *   *   0   240

Regards

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't calculate shipping rates based on city names. Tables rates are calculated on base of region/state and postal code, however there is one thing you can do. which is , since every city has its own zip/postal code so you can add code ranges in zip-postal code column, then it will calculate rates based on city.

However, rates will not be still calculated based on city name hence based on zip/postal code.